# Site is responsive in pc but it is displayed in half of mobile browser

Tags: mobile, responsive-design

A website was working perfectly as responsive in mobile and PC both but it's not working now. It's being displayed at the half of mobile browser. I've also included this in my header::

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

but I can't find the problem. Is there anything I should be adding? Or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this code::

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

and this code::

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

in my page but I removed the second one and it's giving me a better look but scrolling is still a problem. It's giving me left/right scrolling(blank space in right).